# Reading a SquashFS archive

Tags: squashfs

(SquashFS is a compressed filesystem - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS)

I'm looking for a way to read a SquashFS filesystem from a program. So far, I've know about the in-kernel drivers for it, but I'm sure that a userspace library for it must exist somewhere. Any language would be fine, but C is preferred.

Just mounting the filesystem and using it that way is technically possible, but I'd rather avoid that route because the application I'm looking at would involve working with at least a few dozen archives at any given time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just downloaded the code tarball from squashfs.sourceforce.net and there is no kernel code in there. Only userland code in C for `mksquashfs` and `unsquashfs`.

You could probably extract code from unsquashfs.

Comment: The SquasFS drivers are already mainlined into the soon to be 2.6.34

Answer (score 6):

There is a tool called `unsquashfs` which extracts the squashfs image akin to `tar`. It should be bundled with `mksquashfs`

Comment: As of 2023, `mksquashfs` and `unsquashfs` are both bundled in the `squashfs-tools` debian package.

Answer (score 1):

`mksquashfs` and `unsquashfs` are packaged as "squashfs-tools" on my Red Hat system:

> ```
> Name        : squashfs-tools
> Group       : System Environment/Base
> Size        : 160923
> URL         : http://squashfs.sf.net
> Summary     : squashfs utilities
> Description :
> ```
>
> Squashfs is a highly compressed read-only filesystem for Linux.  This package
>   contains the utilities for manipulating squashfs filesystems.
>
> ```
> /sbin/mksquashfs
> /usr/sbin/unsquashfs
> /usr/share/doc/squashfs-tools-3.0
> /usr/share/doc/squashfs-tools-3.0/ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
> /usr/share/doc/squashfs-tools-3.0/CHANGES
> /usr/share/doc/squashfs-tools-3.0/COPYING
> /usr/share/doc/squashfs-tools-3.0/PERFORMANCE.README
> /usr/share/doc/squashfs-tools-3.0/README
> ```

Be warned that squashing and unsquashing are painfully slow. It takes several minutes for a script I wrote to unsquash, modify, and re-squash an 87M `stage2.img` file.